# Blender 2.8 problem with textures and or materials

Tags: modeling, materials

I've been learning blender for the past two weeks, yesterday I was playing with textures and materials, I tried a few like leather, cotton and stuff like that for the pants of the character I'm making, I did not like the outcome so I deleted everything and saved the proyect. Today I watched a few videos to understand more how this works, proceeded to download a few fabric textures to try the same thing again but this time with more knowledge, to find out that something is messing with the textures of my character. I created a new proyect and added the textures to the default cube to see if I was doing the right thing and it worked perfectly. I can't get rid of the colors/textures/materials I have on my character, any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

P.S I have attached a couple of photos in case it helps.

This is how my character looks like with the texture:
[image]

This is how it should look like:[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your setup. Have you selected the character in object mode, and then hit the minus button next to the box containing the material slots?

Comment: what do you need to see? all i want is remove all textures, colors or materials from my character. Already removed all the materials https://i.imgur.com/IN1uPQ1.png

Comment: Yeah, it's very strange that your model is showing colors that "aren't there". Only thing I can think to try is to select your whole character, copy it (ctrl+c), start a new project, delete the default cube, and paste (ctrl+v) your character in. That should clear it of any errant data connected to the old project, and perhaps show you if something is wrong with the settings in the previous problem that may be causing this.

Comment: Hi again Christopher ty for your answer, that was one of the first things I tried, did not work though, the problem is that yesterday I was playing around with blender and I'm not sure what the problem is anymore, I'm starting to think that maybe is a texture painting problem but idk

Comment: I probably did, but my first thought was that the problem was related to texture or material because sometimes I see  missing textures and materials warnings. Thanks again for the answer

Comment: Done I hope this helps ty so much for your time [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Dd0RPlr1" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Dd0RPlr1/)

Comment: Hey, I downloaded your file, opened it, changed nothing but switch back and forth between the render settings and render engines (both cycles and eevee) and what I saw was always this. Is this what you see, or different?   - https://ibb.co/SRyn8ZD

Comment: yes that's what I see, the problem comes when I add a texture to it, thats when I see the weird blue color, I think it might have a bugged texture or something like that. Idk if you can see it the way I do because u dont have the textures I have but Ill upload the blender file with the texture, the mouth and the nose looks  the way it should https://imgur.com/ZMIuKYK and here is the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3Zkyqxny" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3Zkyqxny/)

Comment: I had to UV unwrap again, but after I added a brick (image) PBR material, I was able to get this - https://ibb.co/R9P7vtQ. FYI, the unwrap was a quick and dirty "smart unwrap" - that's why the texture isn't aligned very well. But before I unwrapped, I used a generated texture coordinate and a checker texture, and got this - https://ibb.co/gdPNBbh. Don't know if that helps any - it's the best I can do for now.

Comment: So are you saying that to fix the problem I have to add texture via UV unwrap? I think with the checker texture u have the same problem I have but not with the other one

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can tell it only has one UV map associated with it and it looks like this - https://ibb.co/j6fPgFN. The checker texture is procedurally generated so it doesn't need UV's. I think it should be straighter than that though, but I'm not sure.

Comment: forgive me Christopher my knowledge about blender its still  bad, Is that good? The thing I dont understand is why the mouth and the nose works fine, i think i might painted the whole model but those spots where the texture works just fine

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could call it "bad" - bad for texturing with images at least. When properly unwrapped, it should look more like this (but better because as I said I did a "quick and dirty" unwrap using "smart uv project" - an automatic unwrapping function that doesn't always look so good) - https://ibb.co/Qnvys3k. If you want more info on unwrapping, I've always found this guide helpful - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/

Comment: What a bummer, I was thinking about start over again but believe or not this took me a lot of days to do, I was hoping to find a fix for this because I'm kinda close to my goal. Thanks again for your time Christopher I'll try to keep digging for a solution :)